# How to keep a TextView's content when changing the Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I'm pretty new to Android Development and I've come across a problem with my TextView. I have an XML file that contains a ScrollView and a TextView:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:freezesText="true">
            </TextView>

    </ScrollView>
```

And I have included it in two different XML files

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/story_view"
        layout="@layout/story_view" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/add_text">
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:text="@string/end_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:onClick="endButtonPressed">
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="@string/submit_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="textAdded">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/story_view" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button android:text="@string/save"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:onClick="saveToDevice">
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="@string/facebook"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="saveToFacebook">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I go from the first XML file to the other (and changing the Activity in the process), the content of the TextView disappears. I have tried freezesText but that doesn't seem to work.

Ordinarily I would just pass the content in an intent but my text is in different colours and I want to maintain that.

I could pass a Bitmap image in an intent but I want to avoid that if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: you might use  shared preferences for saving activity state,just go searching  'save activity state in android using shared preferences' you will find tonnes of thread http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=save+activity+state+android+sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happen because when you come back to the first activity, the onCreate method is called, so your textView is a new textView.
Take a look to [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html), here is explained much better.

You can use [**sharedPreferences**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)  or a [**Singleton**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (a design pattern), where the class can be instantiate only one time:

```
public class MySingleton{

    private static MySingleton INSTANCE = null;
    private String textViewInformation;

    private MySingleton() {

    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null)
                        INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

  public String getTextViewInformation(){
    return textViewInformation;
  }

 public void setTextViewInformation(String textViewInfo){
  textViewInformation = textViewInfo;
 }

}
```

and then:

```
 public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
      MySingleton.getInstance(this).setTextViewInformation("textViewText");
     }



  public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

   if(MySingleton.getInstance(this).getTextViewInformation() != null){
     yourTextView.setText(MySingleton.getInstance(this).getTextViewInformation());
   }else{
     yourTextView.setText("new text");
   }
```

Maybe this way it's longer than the shared preferences, but it's very useful.
Excuse my bad english!
I hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Activity state to save some values like

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
    savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
    double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
    int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `sharedpreferences` for this purpose it allows you to store and retrieve data using `key-value pairs`. for satisfying your purpose you need to store your activity state in `sharedpreferences`.

particularly in your case
first you need to store the textview value in shared preferences when you destroy the activity

```
@Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourelement);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            prefEditor.putBoolean("text", tvText .getText().toString());
            prefEditor.commit();
        }
```

Then in `onCreate` you need to set the textview text from your shared preferences.

```
TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourelement);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.contains("text")){
            tvText .setText(prefs.getString("text", ""));
        }
```