# How to send 2 different values from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I'm editing a my friend's code in which there is this method:

```
private void send() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("id", id);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    id.removeAll(id);
}
```

I want to put another value (a double) to the intent. I already read other questions here on SO and tried several solutions, but nothing suit my need. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the first activity, you should do:

```
private void send() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("id", id);
    intent.putExtra("DobleValue", double); // HERE!
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    id.removeAll(id);
}
```

And in the next activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        double dob = b.getDouble("DobleValue");
        ....
    }
```

Also, if you want another way to do this, you can look my answer in this post: [How to keep a TextView's content when changing the Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555594/how-to-keep-a-textviews-content-when-changing-the-activity/24556207#24556207)

Comment: And what about the other extra in the next activity? I used your code and i edited it in this way: http://pastebin.com/03bjAT4F
I receive the right "id", but "0.0" as double (instead of value i sent from previous activity).

Comment: can I see the first activity please?

Comment: Sure. Here is the first activity: http://pastebin.com/WLdBwdRt. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you never modified the value of "distance" (maybe you can send "distanza" ? )

Comment: Sorry, i translated in english for you and i forgot some words.
Anyway the problem is that if i check the value it is right in `if( 50 >= distanza);` then if i check the value in `intent.putExtra("km", distanza);`, it is 0.0. Maybe now i'm too tired to figure out what's the matter...